# openFOAM- visualize vtk files on web viewer VTK.js

Tags: python, vtk, data-conversion, openfoam

I would like to visualize the `vtk` files from openFOAM on the web viewer [VTK.js](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-js/examples/). However, it seems like the `vtk` files cannot be loaded directly and I might need to convert them to other formats such as `vti` or `vtp`. Do you know a simple way to convert `vtk` format to `vti` or `vtp`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

- [foamToVTK](https://www.openfoam.com/documentation/guides/latest/man/foamToVTK.html) now support to export to .vtp/.vti
- You can convert a .vtk file into a .vt* file using a number of tools, [VTK](https://vtk.org) itself, [ParaView](http://paraview.org), [meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio), [pyvista](https://www.pyvista.org/),

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I checked the the first link. I could find how foamToVTK can output a vtp or vti. Could you please be more specific ?
Thank you!

Comment: never used foamToVTK, you can ask on their gitlab : https://develop.openfoam.com/groups/Community/-/issues